# Fixed the td in table scroll

Tags: javascript, html-table, floating

I have a dynamic table which have so many columns and rows
and the problam is I want to stick the th and left-most td when scroll is empty like they are floating on their place not going anywhere with the  scroll moving.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZBeT/1/)  the code is not working in the fiddle because of the

[image]

display is just temporary because in actual it is fetching from database.  I want to float the header and leftmost td having value (hello) and (make it float).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

apply to `#rooms` as below:

```
#rooms {
    position: absolute;
    width: 47px;
}
```

also, give `position: relative` to `<tr>` as below:

```
tr{
    position: relative;
}
```

and `<td>` and `<th>` give `height` to it as below:

```
td, th{
  height: 32px;
}
```

I hope this would help

Comment: Actually, there's no need of `position: relative:` for the rows. But, above all, I highly doubt this works in all browsers...

Comment: It works on all the browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE 8-9) except IE 7,